# Hashmap null convert to int

Tags: java, hashmap

If I do something like this:

I want to see if the value in the map is null or not

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
int val = map.get(arr[i]);
  if(!val){
  ....
```

How do I check if val is null then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Integer val = map.get(arr[i]);
if (null == val) {
    // value is null
}
```

Note the use of `Integer` over `int` when fetching from the map. This works because `Integer`s may be null, while assigning `null` to an `int` results in a `NullPointerException`.